# Error on videos (.mkv) after software upgrade

Tags: video, mkv, mpv-media-player

## My system:

```
Laptop Dell inspiron 15 3000
RAM: 16 GB
SSD 480 GB Kingston
Intel Core i3 7th Generation
OS: Ubuntu 18.04 with Software and System Updates
Web Browser: Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome, Palemoon. All latest.
Terminal emulator: Yakuake, gnome-terminal.
Other Terminal: TTY1
Internet service provider connection speed: 100 Mbps (asymmetric)
```

## The upgrade

Just recently I have run sudo apt upgrade in order to upgrade my software from a terminal. Before this everything everything used to be fine. I was able to play videos both with video and audio. And the mkv files used to run smoothly allowing to select any language/subtitle or any other option in the file.

### The error received

I am using `mpv` to play my mkv and other format files like ogv, mpg, mpeg2, mp4, etc.

After upgrading all the Software in my system, I started having this kind of screen instead of the video itself.

Other video players have similar behavior becoming unresponsive after few seconds and throwing high processor loads, but it seems that they are looking for a codec, plugin or something in order to do a good job, but they aren't reaching it.

### mplayer

Seems to be the only way I can play this videos, with some errors like wrong video duration.

[image]
This video was only played by using the next:

```
geppettvs@DM4:~/Peliculas$ mplayer BIRDS\ OF\ PREY.2020.WEB-DL.1080P-Ignacio\ Hd.mkv 
MPlayer 1.3.0 (Debian), built with gcc-7 (C) 2000-2016 MPlayer Team                                                                                  
do_connect: could not connect to socket                                                                                                              
connect: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing BIRDS OF PREY.2020.WEB-DL.1080P-Ignacio Hd.mkv.
libavformat version 57.83.100 (external)
libavformat file format detected.
[lavf] stream 0: video (h264), -vid 0, Ignacio Hd
[lavf] stream 1: audio (ac3), -aid 0, -alang spa, Ignacio Hd
[lavf] stream 2: audio (ac3), -aid 1, -alang eng, Ignacio Hd
[lavf] stream 3: subtitle (srt), -sid 0, -slang spa, Ignacio Hd
[lavf] stream 4: video (mjpeg), -vid 1
[lavf] stream 5: video (mjpeg), -vid 2
VIDEO:  [H264]  1920x802  0bpp  23.976 fps    0.0 kbps ( 0.0 kbyte/s)
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_va_gl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[vdpau] Error when calling vdp_device_create_x11: 1
==========================================================================
Opening video decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg's libavcodec codec family
libavcodec version 57.107.100 (external)
Selected video codec: [ffh264] vfm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg H.264)
==========================================================================
Clip info:
 title: Aves de Presa (y la Fantabulosa EmancipaciÃ³n de Harley Quinn) (2020) Latino HD WEB-DL 1080P - LatinoMegaHD
 encoder: libebml v1.3.0 + libmatroska v1.4.1
 creation_time: 2020-03-24T06:43:53.000000Z
Load subtitles in ./
==========================================================================
Opening audio decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg/libavcodec audio decoders
AUDIO: 48000 Hz, 2 ch, floatle, 256.0 kbit/8.33% (ratio: 32000->384000)
Selected audio codec: [ffac3] afm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg AC-3)
==========================================================================
AO: [pulse] 48000Hz 2ch floatle (4 bytes per sample)
Starting playback...
Movie-Aspect is 2.39:1 - prescaling to correct movie aspect.
VO: [xv] 1920x802 => 1920x802 Planar YV12 
A:   9.8 V:   9.8 A-V:  0.000 ct:  0.042   0/  0 38%  1%  0.7% 0 0 

Exiting... (Quit)
[mié mar 25 08:08:44 CST 2020] geppettvs@DM4:~/Peliculas$ mplayer BIRDS\ OF\ PREY.2020.WEB-DL.1080P-Ignacio\ Hd.mkv 
MPlayer 1.3.0 (Debian), built with gcc-7 (C) 2000-2016 MPlayer Team
do_connect: could not connect to socket
connect: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing BIRDS OF PREY.2020.WEB-DL.1080P-Ignacio Hd.mkv.
libavformat version 57.83.100 (external)
libavformat file format detected.
[lavf] stream 0: video (h264), -vid 0, Ignacio Hd
[lavf] stream 1: audio (ac3), -aid 0, -alang spa, Ignacio Hd
[lavf] stream 2: audio (ac3), -aid 1, -alang eng, Ignacio Hd
[lavf] stream 3: subtitle (srt), -sid 0, -slang spa, Ignacio Hd
[lavf] stream 4: video (mjpeg), -vid 1
[lavf] stream 5: video (mjpeg), -vid 2
VIDEO:  [H264]  1920x802  0bpp  23.976 fps    0.0 kbps ( 0.0 kbyte/s)
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_va_gl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[vdpau] Error when calling vdp_device_create_x11: 1
==========================================================================
Opening video decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg's libavcodec codec family
libavcodec version 57.107.100 (external)
Selected video codec: [ffh264] vfm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg H.264)
==========================================================================
Clip info:
 title: Aves de Presa (y la Fantabulosa EmancipaciÃ³n de Harley Quinn) (2020) Latino HD WEB-DL 1080P - LatinoMegaHD
 encoder: libebml v1.3.0 + libmatroska v1.4.1
 creation_time: 2020-03-24T06:43:53.000000Z
Load subtitles in ./
==========================================================================
Opening audio decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg/libavcodec audio decoders
AUDIO: 48000 Hz, 2 ch, floatle, 256.0 kbit/8.33% (ratio: 32000->384000)
Selected audio codec: [ffac3] afm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg AC-3)
==========================================================================
AO: [pulse] 48000Hz 2ch floatle (4 bytes per sample)
Starting playback...
Movie-Aspect is 2.39:1 - prescaling to correct movie aspect.
VO: [xv] 1920x802 => 1920x802 Planar YV12 
A:  15.5 V:  15.5 A-V:  0.000 ct:  0.042   0/  0 36%  1%  0.6% 0 0 

Exiting... (Quit)
```

### mpv

[image]
Please notice the `mpv` screen is the black square in the middle of the screenshot.

[image]
I mean: this square.

### mpv information

```
mpv 0.27.2 (C) 2000-2017 mpv/MPlayer/mplayer2 projects                                                  
 built on UNKNOWN                                                                                       
ffmpeg library versions:                                                                                
   libavutil       55.78.100                                                                            
   libavcodec      57.107.100                                                                           
   libavformat     57.83.100                                                                            
   libswscale      4.8.100                                                                              
   libavfilter     6.107.100                                                                            
   libswresample   2.9.100                                                                              
ffmpeg version: 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.
```

### smplayer

[image]
This is `smplayer` with the same video, you can notice some weird artifacts instead of the video.

### smplayer information

```
This is SMPlayer v. 19.10.2 (revision 9245) running on Linux
```

### vlc

[image]
VLC shows a black screen and a line running from left to right, like searching for the proper video codec or something, becoming unresponsive after some seconds.

### vlc information

```
VLC media player 3.0.8 Vetinari (revision 3.0.8-0-gf350b6b5a7)
VLC version 3.0.8 Vetinari (3.0.8-0-gf350b6b5a7)
Compiled by buildd on lcy01-amd64-014.buildd (Sep 11 2019 11:39:37)
Compiler: gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)
This program comes with NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
You may redistribute it under the terms of the GNU General Public License;
see the file named COPYING for details.
Written by the VideoLAN team; see the AUTHORS file.
```

### Other video software information and players used for testing

### ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers                     
built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)                                                               
configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared                                           
libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100                                                                  
libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100                                                                  
libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100                                                                  
libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100                                                                  
libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100                                                                  
libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0                                                                  
libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100                                                                  
libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100                                                                  
libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
```

### parole

```
Parole Media Player 1.0.1
```

### totem

```
totem 3.26.0
```

### libvdpau-va-gl1

As @nobody asked, I checked if `libvdpau-va-gl1` is installed in my system, resulting that I didn't have it.

[image]

After installing I tried to open the video file resulting in a more clean layout but no full video so far.

[image]

Thank you a lot for your wish to help.

### dpkg -l | grep gstreamer

```
geppettvs@DM4:~$ dpkg -l | grep gstreamer
ii  gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0:amd64                      1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1                                  amd64        GObject introspection data for the GStreamer library                                                          
ii  gstreamer-qapt                                  3.0.4-0ubuntu1                                           amd64        GStreamer plugin to install codecs using QApt                                                                 
ii  gstreamer1.0-adapter-pulseeffects:amd64         4.7.2-3~bionic2                                          amd64        Gstreamer adapter
ii  gstreamer1.0-alsa:amd64                         1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1                                  amd64        GStreamer plugin for ALSA
ii  gstreamer1.0-autogain-pulseeffects:amd64        4.7.2-3~bionic2                                          amd64        Gstreamer crystalizer
ii  gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0:amd64                  3.0.26-1                                                 amd64        Clutter PLugin for GStreamer 1.0
ii  gstreamer1.0-convolver-pulseeffects:amd64       4.7.2-3~bionic2                                          amd64        Gstreamer convolver
ii  gstreamer1.0-crystalizer-pulseeffects:amd64     4.7.2-3~bionic2                                          amd64        Gstreamer crystalizer
ii  gstreamer1.0-fluendo-mp3:amd64                  0.10.32.debian-1                                         amd64        Fluendo mp3 decoder GStreamer 1.0 plugin
ii  gstreamer1.0-gl:amd64                           1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1                                  amd64        GStreamer plugins for GL
ii  gstreamer1.0-gtk3:amd64                         1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1                                  amd64        GStreamer plugin for GTK+3
ii  gstreamer1.0-libav:amd64                        1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1                                  amd64        libav plugin for GStreamer
ii  gstreamer1.0-nice:amd64                         0.1.14-1                                                 amd64        ICE library (GStreamer plugin)
ii  gstreamer1.0-packagekit                         1.1.9-1ubuntu2.18.04.5                                   amd64        GStreamer plugin to install codecs using PackageKit
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:amd64                  1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1                                  amd64        GStreamer plugins from the "bad" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:amd64                 1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1                                  amd64        GStreamer plugins from the "base" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386                  1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1                                  i386         GStreamer plugins from the "base" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps                  1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1                                  amd64        GStreamer helper programs from the "base" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:amd64                 1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1                                  amd64        GStreamer plugins from the "good" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly:amd64                 1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1                                  amd64        GStreamer plugins from the "ugly" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio:amd64                   1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1                                  amd64        GStreamer plugin for PulseAudio
ii  gstreamer1.0-tools                              1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1                                  amd64        Tools for use with GStreamer
ii  gstreamer1.0-x:amd64                            1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1                                  amd64        GStreamer plugins for X11 and Pango
ii  libgstreamer-gl1.0-0:amd64                      1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1                                  amd64        GStreamer GL libraries
ii  libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0:amd64             1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1                                  amd64        GStreamer libraries from the "bad" set
ii  libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:amd64            1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1                                  amd64        GStreamer libraries from the "base" set
ii  libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386             1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1                                  i386         GStreamer libraries from the "base" set
ii  libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:amd64            1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1                                  amd64        GStreamer development files for libraries from the "good" set
ii  libgstreamer1.0-0:amd64                         1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1                                  amd64        Core GStreamer libraries and elements
ii  libgstreamer1.0-0:i386                          1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1                                  i386         Core GStreamer libraries and elements
ii  libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer           1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10                                amd64        GStreamer backend for LibreOffice
ii  phonon-backend-gstreamer:amd64                  4:4.9.0-1                                                amd64        Phonon GStreamer 1.0 backend
ii  phonon-backend-gstreamer-common:amd64           4:4.9.0-1                                                amd64        Phonon GStreamer 1.0.x backend icons
ii  phonon4qt5-backend-gstreamer:amd64              4:4.9.0-1                                                amd64        Phonon Qt5 GStreamer 1.0 backend
```

Comment: stupid question is `libvdpau-va-gl1` on your system?

Comment: That's not a stupid question. It is good, indeed. And I have checked and no, I had not installed libvdpau-va-gl1 before. Now that I have it the player's results seems a bit more clear. But no full image so far. Please see the edit at the end of the question with a screenshot or two. And thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Other videos like mp4 are playable? `dpkg -l | grep gstreamer` I only use mpv. `cat .config/mpv/config`  which gpu?

Comment: `cat: .config/mpv/config: No such file or directory`. I have added the results of `dpkg -l | grep gstreamer`. And I don't think this issue is related to the GPU as they worked pretty fine before the Software upgrade and they can be played via mplayer in a terminal. Anyway: `00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5921 (rev 06)` (Default Laptop's Intel GPU.

Comment: Other videos are experiencing the same. MP4 and other format. But certain mp4 videos are playing correctly. Specially those who was made with a cellphone. I guess this is an issue with the codecs. The upgrade should have changed something in my setup which I can't find a way to fix. Thanks in advance to @nobody for the help. (sorry hahaha had to write that)

Comment: would you be so kind and open a chatroom, before a mod comes along? In the moment I have no idea what is going wrong on your system.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105956/discussion-between-geppettvs-dconstanzo-and-nobody).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could revive at least mpv. By installing libvdpau-va-gl1.

> Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_va_gl.so: cannot open shared
>   object file: No such file or directory

Next step was to update the system complete.
Then we created a small $HOME/.config/mpv/config with this content.

```
vo=vaapi  #use vaapi for hardware decoding
hwdec=vaapi # maybe not longer required 
ao=pulse #use pulse for audio overview gives mpv --audio-device=help
```

More options can be read in

```
zless /usr/share/doc/mpv/mpv.conf.gz
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.